# Unable to connect to other device via socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket, wifip2p

I am working on a wireless file sharing app. I have created 2 different AsyncTasks, one for sending and one for receiving. 
In the class used for sending the data, Here is a snippet of the code I use for connecting.

```
client = new Socket();
client.bind(null);
client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(groupOwnerAddress, 8888));
```

In the class used for receiving the data, I create a ServerSocket and a Socket and then call

```
server = new ServerSocket(8888);
client = server.accept();
```

My devices aren't connecting to each other for some reason. In the device that I am sending the data from, I get the following message in the log.

I am pretty certain that my IP address is not wrong because I connected the 2 devices using WifiP2pManager's connect() method. I then got the IP address using by requesting the group information.

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 8888) from /:: (port 38275): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

The error points to this line

```
client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(groupOwnerAddress, 8888));
```

I looked up the error online and it said that the port is not listening.. But when i debug the receiving device, I can see that the debugger stops at this line

```
client = server.accept();
```

From what I can understand, this means that the device is listening on the port.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the server socket (receiver) run first and then run the sender socket (sender) means makes the starting difference between sender and receiver for 5 to 8 second if you run the sender socket first and then start the server socket this **connection failed error** could be come.

And sending the large file from java.io is not the good choice if you are using.Use the java.nio package for handling large file see this http://www.coderpanda.com/java-socket-programming-transferring-large-sized-files-through-socket/

Comment: The wifip2p api itself recommends using an asynctask. so i dont know what youre talking about. As for the running the sender socket after the receiver socket how should I do that?

Comment: I fixed my problem by delaying the the start of the sender. So your solution partly works. If u want, edit your answer to include only that part and I can mark it as the correct answer.